# HTML class not loading in browser

Tags: html, css

in the following code:

```
<div id="homePage">
   <div class="hero">
          
   </div>
 </div>
```

Neither localhost nor heroku accepts the class "hero" into the nested div. All other classes show up upon inspection but not this class. If I inspect the div and add the class in manually there, all related styling applied to the class appears. Why might the browser refuse to load only one class attribute?

*Note* I am using react-bootstrap.

UPDATE: I am attaching pictures for further clarification

Here is the source code as written in my editor:
[image]

Here is how the code is compiled into the browser if you inspect (you'll notice that the #homePage id is applied to the outer div, but the .hero class is not applied to the inner div. This is the source of my confusion.

[image]

I can manually add the .hero class into devtools elements tab so that it looks like this:

[image]

If so, all the styling applied to that class populates the viewport as intended, but obviously this isn't permanent because it will all disappear upon refresh.

Hope that clarifies things. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "does not accept"? It is not in the code? It is not applied? It shows it is applied, but really isn't?

Comment: If it works applying it manually in dev tools.. my only guess would be mis-specification or misspelling in the CSS file.

Comment: The simplest way would be to change the class name to `myhero` or something to see if that appears. `hero` could be a reserved word in react-bootstrap perhaps.

Comment: By "does not accept" I mean that the class is not in the compiled code in the browser as shown by devtools. changed hero class name to heroImage and still the same issue. It is also spelled the same in CSS file (see update above)

Answer (score 1):

Other divs might be hiding that div. Try to you put in your CSS a margin for your div to see where it is located.

Update:

You need to use `className` as the attribute for HTML elements for classes instead of class. Because class can conflict in react. So try like below;

```
return (
<div id="homePage">
  <div className="hero">

  </div>
</div>
);
```

Comment: the hero class already has a height and margin. I took your advice and added one to the div directly in dev tools and it was applied, but that isnt the problem. The problem is getting this class to apply to the div, however when the code is compiled, this class is not included for some reason. That is the problem. See update above. Thanks for your response though.

Comment: I have updated my answer, you can check it mate. You are welcome by the way.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the answer to my question. In react-bootstrap, the markup for adding classes is different for JSX than it is in regular HTML. Instead of

```
<div class="hero">
```

You must label it:

```
<div className="hero">
```

The reason the id was populating is that applying an id to an element in JSX is the same as it is in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the class name "hero".  My guess is that your actual html probably has some small syntactical error, like a missing ", >, /, =, etc.

Also check any Javascript you may have running for anything that removes the "hero" class from a div.

Answer (score 0):

This seems slightly vague, as based on your question it seems you understand that the markup is valid as written.

I concur that it does seem properly written - I have even checked to see if your quotation marks are not utc-8 valid and they seem fine. So either you pasted valid quotation marks, but your source is wrong, or something else is amiss.

Could you perhaps share in what manner this is being applied? Are these HTML tags hard coded, or is something instantiated via javascript?

Also are you saying that the Google/Firefox/Whatever inspector doesn't see class="hero" within the source code, or are you saying the styling itself isn't applied?

I think we need some more clarification to help you best.

Comment: please see the update I gave above. I think that should make everything more clear.

Comment: To answer your other question, the HTML tags are indeed hard coded.